# Ansible regex lookaround cannot replace the pattern

Tags: regex, ansible

My regex can fetch the correct word; however, the ansible fails to change it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdobZ.png)

My ansible code:

```
hosts: all
gather_facts: False
become: true

tasks:
  - name: Checking if chargen configuration is present in the files
    ansible.builtin.replace:
      path:  /etc/xinetd.d/chargen
      regexp: '(?<=disable\s{9}\S\s)yes'
      replace: 'no'
    register: test
   - name: Gathered
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "{{ test }}"
```

Result: it's "ok" but not changed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRp3a.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSOF9.png)

Comment: Try with `ansible.builtin.lineinfile:` and then `regexp: '^(\s*disable\s*=\s*)yes\s*$'`, `line: '\g<1>no'` and `backrefs: yes`.

Comment: hello it works but it only changes the below line. It does not change the one above.  do i have to run the task twice

Comment: Interesting, does it work as expected with `ansible.builtin.replace:`?

Comment: Hi I managed to solve it with ur regex
  tasks:
    - name: Setting Chargen 'disabled' to NO
      ansible.builtin.replace:
        path:  /etc/xinetd.d/chargen
        regexp: '^(\s*disable\s*=\s*)yes\s*$'
        replace: '\g<1>no'

Does \g<1> refers to the 1st group and when use it means apply the following changes that is not encapsulated via group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
tasks:
  - name: Checking if chargen configuration is present in the files
    ansible.builtin.replace:
      path:  /etc/xinetd.d/chargen
      regexp: '^(\s*disable\s*=\s*)yes\s*$'
      line: '\g<1>no'
    register: test
   - name: Gathered
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "{{ test }}"
```

Here,

- `^(\s*disable\s*=\s*)yes\s*$` - matches

  - `^` - start of string
  - `(\s*disable\s*=\s*)` - Capturing group 1 (it can be referred to with `\1` or `\g<1>`): zero or more whitespaces, `disable`, zero or more whitespaces, `=`, zero or more whitespaces
  - `yes` - `yes` string
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `$` - end of string.
- `'\g<1>no'`  replaces the matched line with the value in Group 1 and `no` string.